# VBA ShellExecute "Print" not working with eDocs DM

Tags: vba

I am trying to use VBA code in MS-Access (2010) to open and print documents from eDocs DM (5.3). My BVA code 'opens' documents from eDocs DM but when I replace 'open' with 'print' it does not work. It throws error code 5, which I guess is network security error. Any ideas?

My Code:

```
PrtDoc = "pcdocs://DOCS/210392/R"
RetVal = ShellExecute(0, "open", PrtDoc, vbNullString, 0, SW_SHOW)
MsgBox "RetVal =   " & RetVal, vbOKOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because the underlying DLL (PwdMoniker.dll) does not support a 'Print' function.  You should verify this with the software vendor (OpenText).

Instead of using the 'PCDOCS' protocol, could you not use the DM API or DM Extensions API to download the document first to a local folder, and then use the ShellExecute command to print the document?